# Delete table row dynamically added in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I know this is a topic already debated...and I've read several topics and answers about this...but I didn't solve the issue so I need to ask in detail for my case.

I have an html table in my page, dinamically populated by AJAX data.
Tha html table is the following:

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-centered table-nowrap m-0" id="table_categories">
<thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table_tbody">

</tbody>
</table>
```

The rows in tbody are dinamically added with the followin jQuery code, after an AJAX call to database

```
$.each(data.rows, function(i, item) {
    $('#table_categories tbody').append(`<tr><td><h5 class="m-0 font-weight-normal">${item.text}</h5></td><td><span class="badge badge-light-warning">Active</span></td><td><a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary remove-category" data-id="${item.id}"><i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td></tr>`);
});
```

New added rows are correctly drawed into the table.
Now, the issue: if I click on the mdi-delete icon inside the anchor with class remove-category, I'd like to remove the related row.
To do that I use the following code.

```
$("#table_tbody").on("click", ".remove-category", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let entryId = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url : controller_url + '/remove_category/' + entryId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON"
    }).done(function(response){
        if(response.status) {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();               
        }
    });
});
```

The data are correctly removed from the remote database...but the table rows is not removed; I'm not able to find the issue.

Can I ask for any help or hint to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `$(this)` in a variable so you can access it once you get the ajax response.

```
$("#table_tbody").on("click", ".remove-category", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this); // save $(this)
    let entryId = $this.data("id"); //use $this here
    $.ajax({
        url : controller_url + '/remove_category/' + entryId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON"
    }).done(function(response){
        if(response.status) {
            $this.parents("tr").remove(); // use $this here (again)    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot cloned...it solved the issue. Can I ask the reason? I'd like to understand and learn more about how javascript/jQuery

Comment: I can't explain it in a good way here, just to point you in the right direction: this in JS is not always what you would expect it to be. Google for something like `this JavaScript explained` to get good explanations from people who have more than just a couple of characters like I here on this site.